# Metamask Mobile not working with Goerli dApp?

Tags: metamask, dapps, goerli

I have a dApp im testing on Goerli. It works perfectly fine on desktop, however on mobile, I get errors where I would normally see a transaction appear. I am using the same account on desktop and mobile. Any idea what would be causing this? Is this a known issue?

You can recreate the issue by attempting to withdraw on desktop and mobile. You will see the window pops up without any error flags on desktop, but on mobile, an error warning appears.

mint.hchogz.com/admin

Comment: Did you use integrated metamask web browser? if no you MetaMask just work with it Transactions may fail on other browsers.

Comment: What error are you getting?